# Keep input checkbox and following text on same line

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP code

```
<?php $j = 0; foreach($v->valeur as $valeur) { ?>
 <input type="checkbox" 
 class=" " 
 name="check<?php echo $v->id; ?>[]"
 value="<?php echo $j; ?>"
 <?php if(strpos($v->active,','.$j.',')!==false) echo ' checked'; ?> 
 data-labelauty="<?php echo $valeur; ?>" />
 <?php echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2); ?>
 <?php ++$j; ?>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
<?php } ?>
```

where
`echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2);` generates " Djembe   ".
My problem is that I want the checkbox and the text to be on THE SAME LINE reagardless of screen width.
[See some code and desirde output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu3KP.png)

Answer (score 0):

To keep the checkbox and text on one line, you can use the CSS property "display: inline-block;" on the checkbox and text elements. This will ensure that both elements remain on the same line, regardless of the screen width. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
 class="checkbox" 
 name="check<?php echo $v->id; ?>[]"
 value="<?php echo $j; ?>"
 <?php if(strpos($v->active,','.$j.',')!==false) echo ' checked'; ?> 
 data-labelauty="<?php echo $valeur; ?>"
style="display:inline-block;" />
 <?php echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2); ?>
style="display:inline-block;">
<?php ++$j; ?>
```

Comment: That code did not do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to warp the input and text in tag like label or div and give that tag property `display: inline-block;`

check: https://jsfiddle.net/2tg54uzj/

Comment: When I used 

<form>   
<label><input type="checkbox" 
 class="checkbox" 
 name="check<?php echo $v->id; ?>[]"
 value="<?php echo $j; ?>"
 <?php if(strpos($v->active,','.$j.',')!==false) echo ' checked'; ?> 
 data-labelauty="<?php echo $valeur; ?>"
style="display:inline-block;" />
 <?php echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2); ?>
</label>
</form>

I got one column, that is one checkbox and its text on each row.
I would like to have several checkboxes and its text on each row, see: [link](https://i.imgur.com/UcSMwqq.png)

Comment: Can you check label/form CSS property in your stylesheet maybe any other CSS property is applied on the tag.

Comment: better to use this code so the loop will not create form tag for each input:

`<?php } else if($v->type==4) { ?>
<?php $j = 0; foreach($v->valeur as $valeur) { ?>
            
<label style="display: inline-block;"><input type="checkbox" 
 name="check<?php echo $v->id; ?>[]"
 value="<?php echo $j; ?>"
 <?php if(strpos($v->active,','.$j.',')!==false) echo ' checked'; ?> 
 data-labelauty="<?php echo $valeur; ?>" />
 <?php echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2); ?>
</label>
<?php ++$j; ?>`

Comment: I  added style to a div instead to a form. This worked best for me, so the checked input boxes stay checked after saving:<?php } else if($v->type==4) { ?>
<?php $j = 0; foreach($v->valeur as $valeur) { ?>
<div  style="display:inline-block;">
<input type="checkbox" class=" " name="check<?php echo $v->id; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $j; ?>"
<?php if(strpos($v->active,','.$j.',')!==false) echo ' checked'; ?> data-labelauty="<?php echo $valeur; ?>" />
<?php echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2); ?>
</div>
<?php ++$j; ?>
Maybe the div should be outside the loop, but for now I am glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it like this:

```
<?php } else if($v->type==4) { ?>
<?php $j = 0; foreach($v->valeur as $valeur) { ?>

<div  style="display:inline-block;">

<input type="checkbox" class=" " name="check<?php echo $v->id; ?>[]" 
value="<?php echo $j; ?>"<?php if(strpos($v->active,','.$j.',')!==false) 
echo ' checked'; ?> data-labelauty="<?php echo $valeur; ?>" />
<?php echo $valeur.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 2); ?>
</div>
<?php ++$j; ?>
```